# get method url includes %E2%81%A9 before file name(source), why?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I try to build video streaming server using spring framework.

however, always sending get method like this

```
"http://localhost:8080/resources/%E2%81%A9mov_bbb.mp4"
```

file name is mov_bbb.mp4

how come this happened?
what is %E2%81%A9?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/streamView", method = RequestMethod.GET)

@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/resources/mov_bbb.mp4");
    RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
```

Answer (score 1):

`%E2%81%A9`code is `POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE` or characters is not visible(you can't see because may your editor not supported).

while calling API you send something like `�mov_bbb.mp4` `�` is invisible characters for you.

[reference of unicode](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)

Comment: after changing file name, it resolved!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Those are 3 bytes encoded in UTF-8 for U+2069, a Unicode direction control, POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE. This here is probably a erroneous left-over of an Arabic/Hebrew text entry.
It is not visible, hence was not trimmed manually, and should have been trimmed in software.

Note also: Right-To-Left might be abused to hide a file extension in a file name, say `.exe` displayed as seemingly ending in `.jpg`. (Here not the case.)

The solution seems to reedit the path `/resources/mov_bbb.mp4`. And check that the file indeed does not contain invisibles.